# How to determine if a function is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

I'm in college calc class, so please keep explanations simple.

Let $g(t)=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{t+1}}$.

I've established its domain to be $(-\infty,-1) \cup [0,\infty)$.

I'm not sure how to go about determining boundedness, please provide feedback on my method below. My understanding is that a function is unbounded if it can output arbitrarily large positive or negative values.

My strategy has been to look at what happens to the function when x is close to the edges of the domain. For example if $x=-1.01$ then $\frac{1}{t+1}$ becomes a "large negative value" -10 and thus the whole function becomes $\sqrt{1-{LargeNegativeNumber}}$  and thus on the whole we get $\sqrt{LargePositiveNumber}$ which is unbounded upwards (in the positive y direction).

If we look at another edge of the domain, $ -\infty $, we see that $\frac{1}{-\infty+1}$ becomes a small negative value. Thus the whole function becomes $\sqrt{1-{SmallNegativeNumber}}$ thus it approaches $1$ from above. (This dcheck doesn't alter our understanding of whether g is bounded or not, right?)

Ok let's go on to looking at values close to 0, say $x = 0.01$. In that case $\frac{1}{0.01+1}$ becomes a "large negative value" and the whole function becomes $\sqrt{1-{LargeNegativeNumber}}$ and thus $\sqrt{LargePositiveNumber}$. Ok this confirms our understanding that g is unbounded upwards in the positive y direction.

Ok then I look at what ahppens to the function when $x = \infty$. We see that $\frac{1}{\infty+1}$ becomes a "small positive number" and thus the whole function becomes $\sqrt{1-{SmallPositiveNumber}}$ and thus 1 approached from below.

My conclusion is that the function is unbounded upwards, but the answer says it's just "not bound" which I assume means unbounded upwards and downwards, but I've failed to show unboundedness downwards! What did I do erroneously?

Comment: The function is bounded below by $0$, but unbounded above, so that is enough to say it is "not bound." It only has to be unbounded one way.

Comment: You should probably review $\lim_{t \to 0^+} g(t)$ more carefully. This doesn't change the final result, but I think you got that one wrong. Hint: $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{t+1}} = \sqrt{\frac{t}{t+1}}$

Comment: @user3733558 You're right, I made a mistake. What's the reasoning behind the equivalence in your "hint"? Why does the 1 "disappear"?

I was stuck on lim x->0+ sqrt(1-1/(t+1)) because what is inside sqrt is negative, right? But you removed the 1 somehow....

Comment: @ErikMartinesSanches : the "hint" was just meant to point out a form that feels more intuitive to me when considering the various limits. I just thought it might help you envision the behavior of $g$ more easily. Not that it is particularly necessary in this case, but perhaps you will remember the "trick" in your future explorations (try to algebraically manipulate expressions to present them in a potentially more practical/useful form)